# Remove all rows that contains the IDs in column1 that have at least one specific value on another specific column2 in a Python Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

Like the title say, I want to remove all rows that contains the IDs in column1 that have at least one specific value on another specific column2.
In my case the "specific values" are zeros

```
   column1 column2 column3
    1   1   a
    1   2   b
    1   3   c
    1   0   d
    2   2   e
    2   3   f
    3   0   g
    3   2   h
    3   0   i
    3   3   j
    4   8   k
```

And the output I want is

```
column1 column2 column3
2   2   e
2   3   f
4   8   k
```

Is there a quick command in Python to do this?

Very thankful in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# get rows whcih contain the tigger (here the zeros in column 2)
df_blacklist = df[df["column2"]==0]
# since you want to remove all IDs in column 1 which have at least 1 zero in column 2
# we get a list of "infected" IDs
lst_blacklisted_ids = list(df_blacklist["column1"].unique())
# now we filter for the IDs which are not infected, be aware that "~" inverts the boolean values in the mask
df = df[~df["column1"].isin(lst_blacklisted_ids)]
```

Comment: Nice solution. Thank you!!

Comment: You are very welcome, if the answer works can you accept it and upvote? This way the author of the answer gets some points and also it helps future reader to find the correct answer in case of multiple answers.

Comment: I did upvote but I don't have reputation yet to make the upvote visualize. Now I just accepted the answer. Thanks again!